# How does PuTTY know when its target is busy? (Serial comms)

Tags: c#, serial-port, console-application, putty

I am trying to develop a serial communication tool for a specific application using C#, preferably as a console application. I am basing my design off of PuTTY, which is somewhat clunky for what I'm trying to do but which I consider a generally good piece of software.

When PuTTY is interacting with a device, it seems to know when it is appropriate or inappropriate for the user to enter new commands; while the device being interacted with is busy, PuTTY hides text entered by the user. Then, when the device is idle, all of the text the user has entered during that time is displayed and said text can be modified. This contrasts with, for example, a C# console application using Console.ReadLine, which echoes user-entered text immediately upon it being typed even while data is being asynchronously printed to the console window, which results in the user-entered characters to be dispersed among the text printed by the device.

**How does PuTTY recognize when a device it's interacting with is "busy" in order to implement this text hiding/displaying behavior?**

As a bonus question, **what would be the best way to replicate this text hiding/displaying behavior in a C# console application while retaining the useful features of Console.ReadLine (i.e., memory of past commands, ability to modify input text, ability to traverse input text using arrow keys, etc.)?** Is there perhaps some alternative to Console.ReadLine which retains these features while being more friendly about data being asynchronously printed to the console?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

> it seems to know when ...

You're attributing capabilities to PuTTY that it doesn't have. It is merely a simple program that forwards keyboard input to the serial port, and relays data received from the serial port to the display. This functionality is known as a terminal emulation program.

> How does PuTTY recognize when a device it's interacting with is "busy" in order to implement this text hiding/displaying behavior?

I'm assuming that you have PuTTY configured to to not echo keyboard input, but the connected device is configured to echo what it receives. Such a configuration will perform as you (inaccurately) describe.

PuTTY unconditionally (i.e. always) forwards all keyboard input to the device (unless flow-control is active).
But only the keystrokes that the device accepts are echoed back (to the host running PuTTY)), which are then promptly displayed by PuTTY. The unprocessed keystrokes (which are buffered by the device) are not immediately echoed, so PuTTY would have nothing to display. Only when the device resumes processing its input queue are those stale characters echoed back to the host for PuTTY to display.
Hence the illusion that (as you describe it) PuTTY "*recognizes*" when the device is not "*busy*".

---

> As a bonus question, what would be the best way to replicate this ...

Normally you would not write a program to replicate this behavior. Echoing is for humans that desire feedback.
Reading the echo in your program is possible, but your program should already know what it sends so expecting an echo should be unnecessary. Assuming this device is using a simple request-response protocol, your program can rely on the response as the indication that (a) the request was received and processed, and (b) the device is ready for a new request.